# passing another class's fixture that returns array objects, got 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, arrays, pytest, fixtures

need your insight:

In my own test setup (init_setup), I need to call another test that is already defined in class Test_Create_Tmp(). The issue is, this class has a fixture (init_api) that returns an array of function apis.

In init_setup: at line inv.test_post_inv_data(), i got 'method' object is not subscriptable, because inside it calls object's api by this: init_api["nAPI"].postJsonData(...)

How do I get this working, if I'm not allowed removing the fixture init_api() from that class? 
I know I can get it working, by complete get rid fixture init_api, move its code just inside test_post_inv_data().

### Thanks!

My own setup:

```
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def init_setup(self, read_data):
        #import Test_Create_Tmp class here
        inv = Test_Create_Tmp()
        inv.test_post_inv_data(read_data, inv.init_api)

# this class is defined in another file
class Test_Create_Tmp():
    @pytest.fixture
    def init_api(self, client):
        self.nAPI = NAPI(client)  #NAPI is a class
        self.sAPI = SApi(client)  #SApi is another class
        return {"nAPI": self.nAPI, "sAPI": self.sAPI}

    def test_post_inv_data(self, read_data, init_api):
        ...
        init_api["nAPI"].postJsonData(json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself.  Just need to create the needed objects (ie, nAPI, sAPI) to invoke the call:

inv = Test_Create_Tmp()

init_api = {

```
'nAPI':  NAPI(client),    #create object of NAPI

'sAPI':  SApi(client)     #create object of SApi
```

}

inv.test_post_inv_data(read_data, init_api)